# Did these change in WPF (latest version)?

Tags: wpf

I am reading sams teach yourself WPF in 24 hours from 2008.

I am wondering if a few things have changed in the latest version of WPF. Like I am using .net 4.0 and VS 2010

> Go ahead and add the bindings for
>   ApplicationCommands.Cut,
>   ApplicationCommands.Copy,
>   ApplicationCommands.Paste,
>   EditingCommands.ToggleItalic, and
>   EditingCommands.Underline. The
>   complete markup for
>   TextEditorToolbar.xaml is shown in
>   Listing 10.1.

When I do this

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name="boldButton"
                  Command= "EditingCommands.ToggleBold"
                  ToolTip="Bold">
        <Image Source="Icons/text_bold.png" />
    </ToggleButton>
```

I don't see EditingCommands.ToggleBold in the intellisense list when I do Command="" I do see a whole list of other things. So are they just not shown or what.

Like I see "Copy" and "Paste" but the book is telling me to do

> ApplicationCommands.Copy

So I am not sure if intellisense is giving me a short hand way of doing it or what?

Also it I getting a error on

```
   Command="EditingCommands.Underline"
```

It gives me "Cannot convert underline" and then Vs2010 just crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has changed. Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779.aspx

for an example.

Comment: Hmm I think you are right. I think I had a couple typos. That's why I am wondering why Intellisense is not picking up those commands. Like they are kinda long to write and easy to make mistakes(and it seems like when you make a typo VS2010 likes to crash)

Comment: IntelliSense works best when your code compiles. If the code contains multiple other errors. IntelliSense won't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline
```